# How to set Django template path properly?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, python-3.8, django-3.1

In most recent django documentation "Overriding from the project’s templates directory"
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/
it shows that you can use the following path for templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

I tried using `[BASE_DIR / 'templates']` but I keep getting the following error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`

It all works fine when I change the code to: `[BASE_DIR , 'templates']` or `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'templates')]`, no problem in such case.
Can someone explain what am I missing with the `[BASE_DIR / 'templates']` line?
Thank you.

I'm using Python 3.8 and Django 3.1.

Comment: Using `os.path.join()` would be fine, but you shouldn't use `[BASE_DIR , 'templates']` - that is adding two directories to `DIRS` - the base dir itself and `'templates'` (which might work some of the time as a relative directory)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use `BASE_DIR / 'templates'`, you need `BASE_DIR` to be a [`Path()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path).

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

I suspect that your settings.py was created with an earlier version of Django, and therefore `BASE_DIR` is a string, e.g.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: My setting was created with django 3.0, I later upgraded django to 3.1, but the setting is still there. And indeed it says: ```BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))```, So that could be the right answer.

Comment: All right, I tried and changed settings from ```BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))``` to ```BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent``` and its working fine now. Thank you @Alasdair

Answer (score 1):

Thank you

```
from pathlib import Path 
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```