# Django error saying TemplateDoesNotExist at/

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have an error on my Django Project. The templates folder doens't work. I have the project like this:

```
├── manage.py
├── myProjet
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── app1
├── templates
```

So, I want to use the templates forlder. The template filder is on "/myProjet/templates", not on: "/myProjet/myProjet/templates." The settings.py file is this:

```
BASE_DIR =  os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join( 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And, the error  is raised on the signup function. The singup function is:

```
def SignupPage(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        uname=request.POST.get('username')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        pass1=request.POST.get('password1')
        pass2=request.POST.get('password2')

        if pass1!=pass2:
            return HttpResponse("Your password and confrom password are not Same!!")
        else:

            my_user=User.objects.create_user(uname,email,pass1)
            my_user.save()
            return redirect('login')
        
    return render (request,'signup.html')
```

The error information is this. I have tried to change the base_path in a lot of ways but I always have this error :

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
signup.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.1.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
signup.html
Exception Location: /home/myPC/myProject/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during:  app1.views.SignupPage
Python Executable:  /home//myProject/my_env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/myPC/myProject/pmTools_V1',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/myPC/myProject/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

I don't know how to correct the erorr. I have a 3.8 python version and 4.1.6 DJango version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TemplateDoesNotExist at/ on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359242/templatedoesnotexist-at-on-django)

Comment: No, I have tried and I get the same error @Gameplay

Comment: Your `templates` folder should be under your `app1` folder.

Comment: Ok, but this is a duplicate still

Comment: I changed and it still doens't work @AlexanderSchillemans

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
```

or at least give the full path depending where templates should be.

By the way: the error message "TemplateDoesNotExist at /" is missleading as the "/" is not a search path. You always get that message whenever a template is missing that you address like "xyz.html".

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
signup.html
```

Below the error message that you have posted you should get the info about where the template has been searched for ... something like this:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\ .....         # because of 'DIRS': ...
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ .....    # because of 'APP_DIRS': True, 
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ .....    # because of 'APP_DIRS': True,
```

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: see the update of my answer and check the templates search path list in the error trace

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate folder for templates but you need to probably fix the `DIR` in `TEMPLATES` as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
   'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```